# I have been trying to solve the duplicate key problem in nodeJS with Mongoose, but nothing works

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to build a user model, but I want to make sure that **username and email are unique**. When I created the first user everything was ok, but when I try to create the second user with the same information, I got the some error that I can handle in when I will save, but the duplicate key wasn't there to handle it.

1. This is my schema file code:

   ```
   const UserSchema = new Schema({
       // this username with SchemaType of string
       username: {
           type: String,
           lowercase: true,
           required: [true, "username is required"],
           unique: true,
           trim: true,
           minlength: [4, "try to user longer name"],
           maxlength: [60, "your name is way too long"],
       },
       // virtual name
       name: {
           // name have two properties
           // first is first and refer to first-name
           // second is last and refer to last-name
           first: {
               type: String,
               lowercase: true,
               trim: true,
               minlength: 4,
               maxlength: 20
           },
           last: {
               type: String,
               lowercase: true,
               trim: true,
               minlength: 4,
               maxlength: 20
           }
       },
       password: {
           type: String,
           required: [true, "password is required"]
       },
       email: {
           type: String,
           required: [true, "email is required"],
           unique: true
       },
       active: {
           type: Boolean,
           default: true
       },
       admin: {
           type: Boolean,
           default: false
       },
       meta: {
           update: {
               type: Date,
               default: Date.now()
           },
           timestamp: {
               type: Date,
               default: Date.now()
           }
       }
   });


   UserSchema.virtual("fullname").get(function () {
       // return the concatenation of first and last
       return this.name.first + " " + this.name.last;
   });

   // Create User Model
   const User = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);

   module.exports = User;
   ```
2. And this is my router code where I tried to handle it:

   ```
   router.post("/register", (request, response) => {
       const user = {
           username: request.body.username,
           email: request.body.email,
           password: request.body.password
       };

       if (!user.email && !user.username && !user.password) {
           return response.json({
               "message": "please fill the whole information"
           });
       }
       // put user info in model
       const newUser = new User({
           username: user.username,
           email: user.email,
           password: user.password
       })

       newUser.validate((err) => {
           console.log(err);
       });
       // save User in model
       newUser.save()
       // return response with info
       return response.status(201).json(user);
   })
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the explanation here is quite a simple one. You are specifying the `unique` attribute in your schema for multiple fields, so mongo will not allow you to create multiple entries with the same information. This is quite obvious.

Also, I noticed a bit of irregularity in your code. The save method you are calling returns a `promise`, which means the event loop will not block your code and the response will be returned immediately. For this, you either need to handle your response inside the `then` block or use `async await` throughout your code.

I would suggest the following changes:

```
router.post("/register", (request, response) => {
    const user = {
        username: request.body.username,
        email: request.body.email,
        password: request.body.password
    };

    if (!user.email && !user.username && !user.password) {
        return response.json({
            "message": "please fill the whole information"
        });
    }
    // put user info in model
    const newUser = new User({
        username: user.username,
        email: user.email,
        password: user.password
    })

    newUser.validate((err) => {
       if(err) {
         response.status(403).json({ message: 'Your custom error message' });
       }

       newUser.save().then(res => {
           return response.status(201).json(user);
       }).catch(e => {
           return response.status(500).json({ message: 'Your custom error message' });
       })
    });        
})
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. it helps me so much and I have missed that save is a promise anyway thank you for your effort